# Why does angular-material strip all classes off md-button?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My code:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Login</md-button>
```

But Chrome renders it as:

```
<button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" style="touch-action: pan-y; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><span class="ng-scope">Login</span></button>
```

The classes .md-raised and .md-primary have been stripped even though the source code example in the official tutorials state to use them.

Comment: Try adding them thru ng-class, if that works

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure and not a brain in this. It looks that the main classes like "md-button" are directive´s. Before it starts rendering, it checks maybe the browser or your device. Otherwise the webkit stuff wouldnt work with mozilla.

Im not sure...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were based on a buggy version but it's impossible to tell since you didn't indicate the version in use. There have been some changes lately and this seems to be working fine now.

This:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Login</md-button>
```

Should generate:

```
<button class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="">
    <span class="ng-scope">Login</span>
    <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
</button>
```

This is based on angular-material 0.8.3.